# firebase recycler adapter with multiple views

Tags: android, firebase, adapter

I am trying to create my own custom firebase recycler adapter for a chat app. I want to inflate two views in the adapter, one for the sender and one for the receiver, but don't know how.

How shall I proceed with this?

Comment: My detailed answer to a similar question on Stack should help:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44893961/6551566

Answer (score 0):

To inflate different views in a RecyclerView, you need to implement this function in your adapter:

```
public int getItemViewType(int position);
```

This function is called before `onCreateViewHolder` and allows you to return an `int` depending on the type of the view you want to inflate. You can imagine using an `enum` to achieve this:

```
public enum TYPE {
    SENDER,
    RECEIVER
}
```

This way you will return an int depending on the type (with `type.ordinal()`).

Then you will get your type on the function `onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)`, you will be able to match you type again `TYPE.values()[viewType]`. This way you will return the inflated layout depending on the type.

Finally on onBindViewHolder(TimelineItemViewHolder holder, int position), you will be able either to:

- Call `getItemViewType(int position)` to know how to cast and display your contents
- Using `instanceof` be able to detect what is the type of the ViewHolder you are looking at
- Use an abstract class, extending `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` shared by your two ViewHolder, allowing you to call a common function, like `display(MyObject object)`

Answer (score -1):

```
private static final int RIGHT_MSG = 0;
private static final int LEFT_MSG = 1;
/*Viewholder for messages*/
public static class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
public EmojiconTextView messageTextView;
public TextView messengerTextView;
public CircleImageView messengerImageView;
public ImageView sendimage;
public ImageView videoview;
public TextView messageTime;
public MessageViewHolder(View v) {
super(v);
messageTextView = (EmojiconTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.messageTextView);
messengerTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.messengerTextView);
messengerImageView = (CircleImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.messengerImageView);
sendimage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
videoview = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.videoview);
messageTime = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_time);
}
/*Firebase recycler Adapter*/
mFirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter < FriendlyMessage, MessageViewHolder > (
FriendlyMessage.class, R.layout.item_message, MessageViewHolder.class,
mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(MESSAGES_CHILD)) {
@Override
protected void populateViewHolder(final MessageViewHolder viewHolder,     final FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage, int position) {
mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
viewHolder.messageTextView.setText(friendlyMessage.getText());
viewHolder.messengerTextView.setText(friendlyMessage.getName());
viewHolder.messageTime.setText(DateFormat.format("MMM d, yyyy hh:mm a", friendlyMessage.getMessageTime()));
if (friendlyMessage.getPhotoUrl() == null) {
viewHolder.messengerImageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(Chat.this,
R.drawable.ic_account_circle_black_36dp));
} else {
Glide.with(Chat.this).load(friendlyMessage.getPhotoUrl()).into(viewHolder.messengerImageView);
}
//for show send image
if (friendlyMessage.getImageUrl() == null) {
viewHolder.sendimage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
viewHolder.sendimage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
Glide.with(Chat.this).load(friendlyMessage.getImageUrl()).into(viewHolder.sendimage);
}
//to show the videoattach in videoview
if (friendlyMessage.getVideoUrl() == null) {
Glide.with(Chat.this).load("").placeholder(R.drawable.videoiconcrop).into(viewHolder.videoview);
//viewHolder.videoview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
viewHolder.videoview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
}
@Override
public MessageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
View view;
if (viewType == RIGHT_MSG) {
view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_viewholder2, parent, false);
return new MessageViewHolder(view);
} else {
view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_viewholder1, parent, false);
return new MessageViewHolder(view);
}
}
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
FriendlyMessage model = getItem(position);
if (model.getContactNumber().equals(UserDetails.contact)) {
return RIGHT_MSG;
} else {
return LEFT_MSG;
}
}
};
 /*Xml for messages i try to provide you one side try to make another side by using id same as this layout*/
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:emojicon="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
android:layout_width="32dp"
android:layout_height="32dp"
android:id="@+id/messengerImageView"
android:src="@drawable/ic_account_circle_black_36dp"/>
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/incoming_layout_bubble"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:background="@drawable/balloon_incoming_normal">
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
android:textStyle="bold|italic"
android:text="Receiver"
android:textSize="16dp"
android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
android:paddingBottom="12dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
android:layout_above="@+id/messageTextView"
android:id="@+id/messengerTextView"
android:layout_weight="0"/>
<hani.momanii.supernova_emoji_library.Helper.EmojiconTextView
android:id="@+id/messageTextView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingLeft="6dp"
android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
android:autoLink="web"
android:text="Rahul Agrawal is a good boy but he does not know what he wants."
style="@style/chat_text_message_style"
emojicon:emojiconSize="30sp"/>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/message_time"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:paddingRight="5dp"
android:text="11:15 PM"
android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
style="@style/chat_timings"
android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"/>
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/image"
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="160dp"
android:src="@drawable/ic_account_circle_black_36dp"
android:contentDescription="send_photo"
android:visibility="gone"
android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
<ImageView
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="120dp"
android:id="@+id/videoview"
android:contentDescription="send_video"
android:src="@drawable/videoiconcrop"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:visibility="gone"
/>
</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

may be this code help you out Happy Coding

Comment: When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.